# SQL distributed cache created on Asp.net core startup

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

I was wondering if there is a way to create the SQL distributed cache on startup of the ASP.NET Core 2.1 application.

I know I can run this command 
`dotnet sql-cache create <connection string>  <schema>  <table name>` but this is a manual process. I want to automate this process on startup.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: By `startup` I assume you meand `during deployment`? There's no reason to create the cache each time a web site starts, it should already be there. Why don't you use the *same* deployment technique you use for your other databases? If the cache table is stored in the same database as the application's tables all you need to do is include it in the deployment scripts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two options:

**Options1**

Since we could run command to create the table, we could run the command from code by `Process`.

```
    public static IServiceCollection ConfigureSqlCacheFromCommand(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var options = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IOptions<SqlServerCacheOptions>>();

        var process = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                Arguments = $"/c dotnet sql-cache create \"{options.Value.ConnectionString}\" { options.Value.SchemaName } { options.Value.TableName }",
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = false,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true
            }
        };
        process.Start();
        string input = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        process.WaitForExit();
        return services;
    }
```

**Option2**

For `dotnet sql-cache` command, it also calls [dotnet-sql-cache](https://github.com/aspnet/DotNetTools/tree/master/src/dotnet-sql-cache), and you could implement the code to create the table programmly.

```
        private static int CreateTableAndIndexes(SqlServerCacheOptions options)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(options.ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            var sqlQueries = new SqlQueries(options.SchemaName, options.TableName);
            var command = new SqlCommand(sqlQueries.TableInfo, connection);

            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow))
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    command = new SqlCommand(sqlQueries.CreateTable, connection, transaction);

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    command = new SqlCommand(
                        sqlQueries.CreateNonClusteredIndexOnExpirationTime,
                        connection,
                        transaction);

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

For calling `CreateTableAndIndexes`, you could implement this extension method:

```
        public static IServiceCollection ConfigureSqlCache(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var options = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IOptions<SqlServerCacheOptions>>();
        int result = CreateTableAndIndexes(options.Value);
        return services;
    }
```

For configuring in `Startup.cs`

```
        services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options => {
            options.ConnectionString = @"Server=localhost\MSSQLSERVER01;Database=IISWindows;Trusted_Connection=True;";
            options.TableName = "CacheFromCommand";
            options.SchemaName = "dbo";
        });

        //services.ConfigureSqlCache();
        services.ConfigureSqlCacheFromCommand();
```

**Note**

- `SqlQueries` is from [SqlQueries](https://github.com/aspnet/DotNetTools/blob/master/src/dotnet-sql-cache/SqlQueries.cs).
- install package `Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils`.
- Register `ConfigureSqlCache` after `services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache`

Comment: To anyone trying to go with the second option, this is not possible anymore due to the SqlQueries class being internal (protection level) to the sql-cache tools program, thus it's not possible to access it anymore. As another workaround, you could always have the command run as part of your build/deployment, for example via your csproj file. Unless I'm just misunderstanding how to implement the code/where to run it.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, if you use [FluentMigrator](https://fluentmigrator.github.io/), here is the SQL schema (as of .NET 6) being converted into a FluentMigrator migration:

```cs
using FluentMigrator;

/// <summary>
/// Migration for cache table at the given <see cref="tableName"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// <para>
/// This should actually be the same as when executed with the .NET tool
/// <c>dotnet sql-cache [create|script] dbo testCacheTable</c>.
/// </para>
/// <para>
/// Implement this and add a proper <see cref="MigrationAttribute"/> for <see cref="FluentMigrator"/>.
/// </para>
/// </remarks>
public abstract class CreateCacheTableMigration : AutoReversingMigration
{
    private readonly string tableName;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a cache table at the given <see cref="tableName"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tableName">The table name, where you want to create a cache table.</param>
    protected CreateCacheTableMigration(string tableName) =>
        this.tableName = tableName;

    public override void Up()
    {
        Create.Table(this.tableName)
            .WithColumn("Id").AsFixedLengthString(449).NotNullable().PrimaryKey()
            .WithColumn("Value").AsBinary(int.MaxValue).NotNullable()
            .WithColumn("ExpiresAtTime").AsDateTimeOffset().NotNullable()
            .WithColumn("SlidingExpirationInSeconds").AsInt64().Nullable()
            .WithColumn("AbsoluteExpiration").AsDateTimeOffset().Nullable();

        Create.Index("Index_ExpiresAtTime")
            .OnTable(this.tableName)
            .OnColumn("ExpiresAtTime")
            .Ascending()
            .WithOptions().NonClustered();
    }
}
```

It is based on this auto-generated SQL command with `dotnet sql-cache script dbo testCacheTable -o dotnet-sqlcache-script.sql`, but generalized for any database table name:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testCacheTable](Id nvarchar(449) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS NOT NULL, Value varbinary(MAX) NOT NULL, ExpiresAtTime datetimeoffset NOT NULL, SlidingExpirationInSeconds bigint NULL,AbsoluteExpiration datetimeoffset NULL, PRIMARY KEY (Id))
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Index_ExpiresAtTime ON [dbo].[testCacheTable](ExpiresAtTime)
```

Answer (score -1):

How do you want to automate this? I am sure but there are many ways to add a distributed cache.

You can see the samples the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-2.1